# how to reshape a dataset for RNN/LSTM model?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, classification, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an RNN/LSTM model for binary classification 0 or 1

a sample of my dataset (patient number, time in mill/sec., normalization of X Y and Z, kurtosis, skewness, pitch, roll and yaw, label) respectively.

```
1,15,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0

1,31,-0.248010047716,0.00378335508419,-0.0152548459993,-86.3738760481,0.872322164158,-3.51314800063,0

1,46,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0

1,62,-0.267422664673,0.0051143782875,-0.0191247001961,-85.7662354031,1.0928406847,-4.08015176908,0
```

and this my code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(7)

train = np.loadtxt("featwithsignalsTRAIN.txt", delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt("featwithsignalsTEST.txt", delimiter=",")

x_train = train[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
x_test = test[:,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
y_train = train[:,8]
y_test = test[:,8]

# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, dropout=0.2, input_dim=6))
model.add(Dense(4, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 2)
```

I am trying to reshape the dataset to be able to feed it to an RNN/LSTM model.

because it gives me the following error

> Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (1415684, 6)

can anyone help me? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please **do not** ask the same question multiple times. You could have just edited the previous question with the additional improvements, and this will already bring it to the top of the active questions feed, providing new attention to answerers.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) which converts your data into sequences of a fixed window size. Currently you are passing the entire dataset (..., 6), if you use a sliding window let's say size 10 (this might not necessary correspond to 10ms depending on your data), the generator will give inputs of shape (..., 10, 6) which is what the LSTM expects. The LSTM will process the 10 timesteps, ie the datapoints in that window and the model will make a prediction.